# How to load multiple text file into Google text to speech?

Tags: python, google-api, google-text-to-speech

I have been using google text to speech API because of how great the voices are. The only problem is been trying to find how to make it user friendly. The biggest thing is google text to speech can only accept text files with 5000 or fewer characters. The main issue that, I have been finding is that currently all I can do is use a single text file copy and paste my stuff on there before saving. Does anyone know how can I upload a folder filled with text files to make it quicker? Plus also saving the mp3 instead of overwriting them?

```
# [START tts_ssml_address_imports]
from google.cloud import texttospeech
import os
import html

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 
# [END tts_ssml_address_imports]


# [START tts_ssml_address_audio]
def ssml_to_audio(ssml_text, outfile):
    # Generates SSML text from plaintext.
    #
    # Given a string of SSML text and an output file name, this function
    # calls the Text-to-Speech API. The API returns a synthetic audio
    # version of the text, formatted according to the SSML commands. This
    # function saves the synthetic audio to the designated output file.
    #
    # Args:
    # ssml_text: string of SSML text
    # outfile: string name of file under which to save audio output
    #
    # Returns:
    # nothing

    # Instantiates a client
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

    # Sets the text input to be synthesized
    synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=ssml_text)

    # Builds the voice request, selects the language code ("en-US") and
    # the SSML voice gender ("MALE")
    voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(language_code='en-US',
                                                    name="en-US-Wavenet-D",
                                                    ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.MALE))

    # Selects the type of audio file to return
    audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(audio_encoding="LINEAR16", pitch = 0, speaking_rate = 0.9)

    # Performs the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
    # voice parameters and audio file type
    response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)

    # Writes the synthetic audio to the output file.
    with open(outfile, 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        print('Audio content written to file ' + outfile)
    # [END tts_ssml_address_audio]

def main():
    # test example address file
    file = 'input_text.txt'
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
    ssml_text = text
    ssml_to_audio(ssml_text, 'file_output_speech.mp3')
    # [END tts_ssml_address_test]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```